How to prove $\Bbb C[X,1/X] $ is neither Noetherian nor indecomposable as a$\Bbb C[X]$-module
How to prove $\Bbb C[X,1/X]$ is a Noetherian $\Bbb C[X]$-module? And is it a indecomposable module?
I foud $\Bbb C[X,1/X]$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb C[X,Y]/(XY-1)$, then I can get that it is a Noetherian ring, but I don't know how to prove it is a Noetherian $\Bbb C[X]$-module.

@moderators: Should the title (which is an incorrect statement) be corrected?

Let $R$ be be any integral domain and $p \in R$ be a non-zero element (in your case, $R = \mathbb{C}[X]$, $p = X$). Then the $R$-module $R[1/p] \subseteq Q(R)$ is generated by the set $\left\{\frac{1}{p^k} : k \geq 0\right\}$. It is finitely generated if and only if there is some $n \geq 0$ such that $\frac{1}{p^{n+1}}$ lies in the submodule generated by the previous generators, which is just the one generated by $\frac{1}{p^n}$. So it happens iff there is some $r \in R$ with $\frac{1}{p^{n+1}} = r \cdot \frac{1}{p^n}$, which means that $p^{n+1}$ divides $p^n$, i.e. that $p$ divides $1$, i.e. that $p$ is a unit.
So when $p$ is not a unit, $R[1/p]$ is not a finitely generated $R$-module. This also implies that it is not a Noetherian $R$-module. And when $p$ is a unit, the module is just $R$, boring.
Now assume that $R$ is also a PID, and that $p$ is a prime element. Then $R[1/p]$ is a PID just as $R$ is (easy result about localizations of PIDs). Also, $R[1/p]$ is an indecomposable $R$-module iff $R[1/p]$ is an indecomposable $R[1/p]$-module, because direct summands which are $R$-submodules are easily seen to be also $R[1/p]$-submodules.
So this reduces the problem to: If $R$ is a PID, then $R$ is an indecomposable $R$-module. That's easy: If $R = aR + bR$ with $a,b \neq 0$, then $0 \neq ab \in aR \cap bR$.

In your case $\mathbb C[x,1/x]$ is not finitely generated as a $\mathbb C[x]$ module. Indeed, note that $\mathbb C[x]$ is a graded algebra, with grading given by:
$$\mathbb C[x]=\bigoplus_{i=0}^{\infty}\{\text{homogenous polynomials of degree i}\}$$
Then $\mathbb C[x,x^{-1}]$ inherits a grading given as follows: an element $p(x)/x^k$ of $\mathbb C[x,x^{-1}]$ is homogenous if $x^kp(x)$ is a homogenous polynomial in $\mathbb C[x]$, and has grading $\deg p(x)-k$. One can easily verify that this is well defined. Suppose that $\{f_1,\dots, f_n\}$ is a finite generating set of $\mathbb C[x,x^{-1}]$, then we can decompose each $f_i$ into a finite sum of homogenous elements:
\begin{align}
f_i=\sum_{j=-k_i}^{n_i} p_{ij}(x)
\end{align}
where $\deg p_{ij}(x)=j$. Since this set is finite then a generator with minimal homogenous part $\deg p_{ij}=-m$ for some $m\in \mathbb N$. Now, $1/x^M$ with $M>m$ cannot lie in the span of $\{f_1,\dots, f_n\}$, as the action of $\mathbb C[x]$ only increases the degree or keeps the degree the same of homogenous polynomials. It follows by way of contradiction that $\mathbb C[x,x^{-1}]$ cannot be finitely generated.
Now suppose that $\mathbb C[x,x^{-1}]\cong M\oplus N$ as $\mathbb C[x]$ modules, then for some $m\in M$ and $n\in N$, we have that $1=m+n$. Moreover, we have that there exists some large enough $k\in \mathbb N$ such that $x^k m, x^kn\in \mathbb C[x]$. I claim that $(x^kmn)\in M\cap N$. Indeed $(x^km)n\in N$, and $(x^kn)m\in M$ so the claim follows. Since $M\cap N=\{0\}$ it follows that since $\mathbb C[x,x^{-1}]$ is an integral domain that either $m$ or $n=0$. Suppose without loss of generality that $n=0$, then $1\in M$ implying that $\mathbb C[x]\subset M$. Let $n\in N$ be arbitrary, then again for some $k$ we have that $x^kn\in \mathbb C[x]\subset M$, so $x^kn\in M\cap N$ hence $n=0$ for all $n\in N$. It follows that $\mathbb C[x,x^{-1}]$ is indecomposable, as any direct sum must have $M$ or $N$ be the trivial module.

You may also want to add "Noetherian module" instead of just ending with Noetherian; $\mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1}]$ is a Noetherian ring since it is the localization of a Noetherian ring: $\mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1}]=S^{-1}\mathbb{C}[x]$ where $S$ is the multiplicative set ${1,x,x^2,\cdots}$.

Might also want to address the other half of the question.

Strictly speaking you do not prove that there is no finite generating set. Also, the remark about Noetherian rings is slightly offtopic.

@rschwieb I will when I get back to my laptop. I missed that part of the question.

@CraniumClamp what do you mean? An $R$-module cannot be Noetherian if it is not finitely generated.

@MartinBrandenburg Fair enough. I will update my answer with a proof that this is the minimal generating set of $\mathbb C[x,1/x]$.

There is no minimal generating set in this case.

@MartinBrandenburg *that there is no finite generating set

@rschwieb added.
